# External USB hard drive acting like internal drive

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, disk-utility, osx-mountain-lion

The power went out and my external hard drive got pretty messed up. After several repair attempts I gave up and tried formatting the thing. I wasn't watching, but I believe Disk Utility hung on "unmounting disk" then crashed.

Now whenever I go back into it I see this:

[image]

(including Recovery Mode).

I can't do anything with it. The partition is locked.

How do I format this thing back to normal?

Comment: Try gpart tool in linux

Comment: And if I don't own a linux computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by entering `diskutil list` in Terminal, finding the disk (my external drive was 500gb so I located the 500gb disk listed).  And entering: `diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ NewDrive disk1`.  It took a couple of seconds but now the external drive is back to normal!  I did loose my backup but I'll just make another.